# java.math.BigInteger, pow method only accepts int

Tags: java, security, biginteger

I'm doing a DSA Signature Verification and Validation assignment, I need to perform a calculation which is like this: `v = (((g)^u1(y)^u2) mod p) mod q`, where g, u1, y, u2, p and q are all `BigInteger` objects, I got stuck with `g^u1` and `y^u2`, I want to use the [pow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#pow(int)) method to do the calculation, but this method only accepts `int` parameter, so I'm not able to calculate `g^u1` like this:

```
g.pow(u1);
```

It's resonable that this method only accepts int parameter, because in this case, `g` is a 1024 bit prime, and `u1` here equals `666075361584433975742185154706661067887879287196`, the result of `g^u1` will become extremely large. My question is, how should I perform the calculation of `v = (((g)^u1(y)^u2) mod p) mod q`.

Comment: You are going to do `mod p` anyway - so why don't you use [BigInteger.modPow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow(java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed `g^u1` becomes very large. However, you can take advantage of the fact that

```
a * b  mod  n
```

can be computed as

```
(a mod n  *  b mod n)  mod  n
```

Here, `a = g ^ u1` and `b = y ^ u2`, and these computations can be done efficiently using [modPow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow(java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger)). `((g)^u1(y)^u2) mod p` will be:

```
g.modPow(u1,p).multiply(y.modPow(u2,p)).mod(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to do `mod p` anyway - so why don't you use [BigInteger.modPow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow(java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger))

Note that

```
g^u1 * y^u2 mod p == (g^u1 modp * y^u2 mod p) mod p
```